# Which Drones are most popular for speed, durability , long battery life?

Tags: quadcopters, dji-mavic-mini, racing, battery-capacity

Also I’m having trouble finding good drones tha can do flips and have good quality of winds resistance and durability, which drone will be worth my time and money ; I have had Dij mavic loved it! But no tricks or flips or anything

Answer (score 1):

Generally, drones that do "flips" are FPV and scratch-built.

DJI and others have things that come close, but as someone who cuts/designs/builds/flies, nothing comes close to a scratch-build FPV for speed and tricks, period!

Wind resistance (performance in the wind) is several factors. The drivetrain (battery potential, props, motors) and the drone's aerodynamics are the most important.  With little issue, I have flown my 5" drones in 60mph winds. Not fun flights. 5" drones in FPV are stable up to 15-20mph winds, 30mph + is felt, 40mph+ is hard to fly in.  But if you have the power wind is no problem.

Battery life is poor for speed and "tricks"; the only way to get the performance is to toss long flights out the window.  These drones are all motor and battery, little else.

Lower KV motors use higher-pitch props and spin slower.  That is the formula for long flights and battery conservation. Not tricks where inertia works against you.

FPV flights are 3 minutes of flying hard, with high KV motors and various pitches. Higher KV motors spin up and down faster than big lower KV motors.

Re "which drone will be worth my time and money" that's on you. If you want speed and freestyle, you are stuck in scratch-building. The DJI and off-the-shelf units are far from anything in the FPV domain. These types of flights (in which I specialize) break drones like crazy; if you can't repair units yourself, this is NOT a wise direction to go, as it will burn money.

Put into financial terms - as an experienced pilot; I learned to fly trees (literally IN the trees). It took about 1 year to learn, and I broke $2000 of gear learning.  If I were not self-building, this would have been 10x more.